# Check Dependency When Delete a object on Django

Tags: python, django, relational-database

Here is the my code in model

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name_role = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_role
class UserProfile(models.Model):

      user = models.OneToOneField(User)


      role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
      create_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)
      create_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
      modified_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)
      modified_date= models.DateTimeField(null=True)
      status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

When A role will be deleted, I want to check if any UserProfile object is related to the role object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by accessing the reverse `ForeignKey` field from Role. Something like:

```
if role_instance.userprofile_set.all():
   print "Care, role is related to userprofile instances"
else:
   print "You are safe to go"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting this

```
role = Role.objects.get(name_role="rolename")
role.user_profile_set.all() #check if any before delete
```

Try this also

```
role.userprofile_set.all()
```